# Testing for significant change between answers to two questions in the same survey

Tags: statistical-significance, survey

Apologies if I am missing necessary information here - my stats knowledge is rusty.

I am analysing responses to questions from survey, where there are two questions as follows:

Q1. What were you doing before event?

Q2. What were you doing after event?

with the same N responses to each question, and only one response allowed.

I want to know if event had a statistically significant impact on the numbers for each response;

e.g. if 119 people chose response n for Q1, and 150 people chose response n for Q2, is this a significant change?

One issue I have is that not all participants in the sample (although a relatively small number) responded to both questions, and so I assume I will have to use percentages rather than frequencies.

Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.